# Trigger Update after insert Oracle

Tags: oracle

Хочу создать триггер, который будет апдейтить значение количества товара(отнимать 1) в таблице продукты, при добавлении нового заказа в таблицу Order_Client, но возникли трудности

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Update_Product
AFTER INSERT ON Order_Client
FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN

UPDATE Product set quantity=(quantity-1)  from Order_Client where Product.id_product=new.Order_client.id_product;

END;
```

Comment: Каково характера трудности возникли?

Comment: Что за диковинный синтаксис UPDATE? Почему :new без двоеточий?

Comment: @hinotf Был бы нормальный синтаксис и `new` с двоеточиями - не было бы вопроса...